# What does "/* /index.html 200" do? I saw it a _redirects file in a react app

Tags: reactjs, routes

/* /index.html 200

I know it has to do with redirecting the page but when is it useful and how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the other answer, I read that this particular case has to do with the fact that react apps are handled as single-page-applications (SPAs), which causes https://yourapp.netlify.app/about to throw a 404 error by default.

Answer (score 0):

Some web hosting services like Netlify or GitHub Pages require redirect rules to know how to handle client routing, that's why you must specify that in a `_redirect` or some other platform-specific configuration file (for instance: `nelitfy.toml` for Netlify or `staticwebapp.config.json` for Azure Web App).